# SQL Server reading in Time values

Tags: sql-server, bcp

I have the scenario where I have written a time column from a SQL Server database to a file using BCP.

I want to read the time in another program but I am unable to determine the format used to write the time to disc.

For example: the time 23:00:00 is written as 05 00 58 A5 C8 C0

05 I am guessing is the length of the data, can anyone tell me how to interpret the rest of the values?

Comment: What output format are you using? Why not just export it as text?

Comment: The column is Time(7).  The BCP command is using -n (native database data types of the data).

Comment: How did you call BCP? What format did you specify? BCP can export data as text just fine. Use the `-c` parameter to export data to text files. `-n` is a *binary* format meant to transfer data between SQL Server instances

Comment: Exporting to text files is described in the docs, in [Use Character Format to Import or Export Data (SQL Server)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/import-export/use-character-format-to-import-or-export-data-sql-server). Simply using `-c` will export the data using defaults. Other options and/or format files can be used to specify headers, separators, text qualifiers etc

Comment: If you want to take a shot at reverse engineering this yourself: try `SELECT CONVERT(VARBINARY(MAX), CONVERT(TIME(7), '23:00'))` and work your way from there. Specifically, observe the difference between converting 00:00:00 and 00:00:01. If at all possible, use some suitable text format; if not, use BCP itself to decode the values into a table (that's what it's there for). I mean, you *can* decode this independently, but there's just not much practical *point*.

Comment: bcp was called via the command line with the -n option.  No other options were specified (other than connection ones).  Currently we are restricted to using -n rather than -c.

Comment: Better yet, observe the difference between `00:00:00.0000001` and `00:00:00.0000002`. It's a little endian integer counting the number of 100 ns intervals. In your example, `select convert(bigint, 0xc0c8a55800) / 3600 / 1e7` gives 23 hours. In .NET, `new DateTime(0xc0c8a55800).TimeOfDay` does the trick -- the formats are not coincidentally compatible.